# AutoGluon LightGBM Model Predictions Outside of AutoGluon predict()

Tags: python, c++, c, automl

I have a stack ensemble of bagged LightGBM models fit with AutoGluon in Python.

Is there a way to perform the same inference as AutoGluon's predict() on this model, except entirely/mostly outside of AutoGluon, for example, with LightGBM's C API?

I'm aware of `predictor._trainer.load_model()` which returns a `autogluon.tabular.models.lgb.lgb_model.LGBModel` object, but am unclear how I would make predictions with that model in LightGBM directly.